# Привязка button к Int

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

У меня есть две кнопки в DataTemplate. Нужно привязать их к свойству типа int так, что бы по нажатию одной кнопки переменная увеличивалась, по другой уменьшалось. Уважаемы знатоки, прошу помощи.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="PriceItems">
    <StackPanel Background ="Azure"  Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10,10">
        <Button x:Name="IncrementBtn" Content="+" FontSize="18" Width="80"  />
        <Label x:Name="CntLabel"  Content="{Binding DataContext.TicketCnt, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="16"/>
        <Button x:Name="DecrementBtn" Content="-" FontSize="18" Width="80" Margin="10,10"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Сделать ViewModel с 2 командами и полем int, привязать кнопки к командам.

Comment: Я новичок  в WPF, пишу без MVVM, можно поподробнее как это сделать?

Comment: Пример - https://github.com/ReedCopsey/Gjallarhorn.Bindable/tree/master/samples/ElmInspiredOne/WpfElmInspiredOneCSharp

Comment: вы можете обходиться без дополнительных библиотек, но с ними код будет намного проще и понятнее

Comment: Суть вот в чем: вы можете решить эту конкретную проблему и без MVVM, но это будет костыльный код. Если вы хотите работать с WPF тем способом, как оно задумывалось разработчиками, то вам следует изучить MVVM и его применение к WPF. Благо информации по этой теме полно.

Comment: @MS24, а почему в DataTemplate? Приведите код как это реально у вас выглядит

Comment: @Андрей возможно речь идет об элементе списка

Comment: @MS24, [отредактируйте вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/718342/edit), не нужно пихать в комментарии этот код

Comment: Я извиняюсь, я совсем новичек, не могу разобраться как это сделать

Comment: Под вопросом кнопка "править". Ну и + я вам ссылку дал на правку поста вашего

Comment: DataTemplate нужен для того, что я не знаю заранее какое количество таких контролов у меня может быть. Вообщем Задача такова, есть label  который отображает количество билетов которые пользователь желает приобрести и соответственно две кнопки + и - по нажатию на которые должно увеличиваться число билетов к покупки.

Comment: @MS24, а почему привязка идет к `TemplatedParent`, у вас это всё в стиле что ли?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Допустим, вы выводите в окне некую коллекцию элементов. Пусть тип этих элементов `Item`:

```
class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...

    int v;
    public int Value
    {
        get => v;
        set 
        {
            v = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Value)));
        }
    }
}
```

Не буду пугать вас MVVM, я просто привяжу коллекцию этих элементов в конструкторе окна:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    IC.ItemsSource = new[]
    {
        new Item { Value = 10 },
        new Item { Value = 12 },
        new Item { Value = 15 },
        new Item { Value = 22 },
        new Item { Value = 27 }
    };
}
```

Разметка:

```
<ItemsControl Name="IC">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="2">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="24"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                <Button Content="+" Grid.Column="1" Margin="2,0"
                        Click="Plus_Click"/>
                <Button Content="-" Grid.Column="2"
                        Click="Minus_Click"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Обработчики событий:

```
private void Plus_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((Item)(sender as Button).DataContext).Value++;
}

private void Minus_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((Item)(sender as Button).DataContext).Value--;
}
```

[image: 1000]

Comment: Работает! ) Вот только я немного не понял каким образом мы получаем доступ к коллекции с помощью этого кода: ((Item)(sender as Button).DataContext).Value--; Ведь кнопка ни к чему не привязана?

Comment: Это делает `ItemsControl`, он устанавливает для своих элементов `DataContext`

Comment: Спасибо большое!  Я хотел сделать подобным образом, но я почему-то считал, что для каждого контрола будет свой DataContext.

Comment: Да, доступ не к коллекции, а к конкретному элементу этой коллекции, каждая кнопка к своему элементу привязана